# The correct way to start animation as soon as fragment loads

Tags: android, android-animation

I got a fragment in which there's an animation of a count down clock. I want to start the animation as soon as the fragment loads without any intervention from the user.

What I do now is calling the following method in `onCreateView`:

```
private void startCountDownAnimation()
{
    final int totalSeconds = secondsToStart + minutesToStart * 60;
    mRingProgressBar.setTotalSeconds(totalSeconds);
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("countdown");
    handlerThread.start();

    Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
            {
                //int secondsPassed = 0;
                int secondsLeft = totalSeconds;

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if(secondsLeft == 0)
                    {
                        //fragment transaction
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    //final int currentProgress = Math.round(((float) secondsPassed)/((float) totalSeconds)*100f);
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            mRingProgressBar.setSeconds(secondsLeft);
                            secondsLeft--;
                            //secondsPassed++;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 1000);

        }
    });
}
```

This seems to work including when the app goes to the background.

I just want to know if what I'm doing is the correct way to handle the animation:

1) Is `onCreate` the correct place to call this method?

2) Can I have some issues of the app going to the background or if the screen blackens after a while?

3)Anything else I should change?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a Timer inside an Handler as the Timer is already asynchronous. The Timer is known to generate memory leaks so I'd suggest to use a [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) instead.
You should probably create the timer in onCreate and start it in onResume and stop it in onPause. Then you update the view in the onTick but you probably need to check if the view is available or not (view != null)